# How to get json data instead of XML using php curl(Exact online)

Tags: php, json, xml, curl

I'm trying to use PHP's curl to make an api request, and I want to get json as response but I keep getting XML code.

```
$curl_Items = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl_Items, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://start.exactonline.nl/api/v1/1234567/logistics/Items?$select=Code,Description',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "Content-type: application/json;charset=utf-8",
        "Authorization: Bearer $access_token",
        "Cache-Control: no-cache",
        "Postman-Token: f181bd2f-5621-49ee-b1a5-d9f73a2a8825"
    ),
));


$ResultItems = curl_exec($curl_Items)
```

This is stated on the exact online FAQ page:

> An Exact Online API request supports two data formats: JSON and XML. They are specified in the header, as follows:
>
> ```
> Content-Type : application/json
> Content-Type : application/xml
> ```

Comment: do you have a link to this online FAQ or a guide? My best guess is that you would need to call another URL for getting JSON response

Comment: @sietse85 https://support.exactonline.com/community/s/knowledge-base#All-All-DNO-Content-faq-rest-api

Comment: Content-type: is written with a lowercase T, normally this is no issue, but what if the endpoint needs case sensitivity? It's a wild guess but try upercase your second T in Content-type

Answer (score 3):

I found the problem Content-Type: application/json is used to post data and give information about what your sending. I needed to use `Accept:application/json` to get json data from the REST API.

Code:

```
$curl_Items = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl_Items, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://start.exactonline.nl/api/v1/12345678/logistics/Items?$select=Code,Description',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "Accept:application/json",
        "Authorization: Bearer $access_token",
        "Cache-Control: no-cache",
        "Postman-Token: f181bd2f-5621-49ee-b1a5-d9f73a2a8825"
    ),
));


$ResultItems = curl_exec($curl_Items);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood the question, but if i did.
Then this could be your answer:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$myArr = array("John", "Mary", "Peter", "Sally");
echo json_encode($myArr);
 ?>
```

Comment: his problems is he keeps getting xml, whilst he is providing a Content-Type header for JSON, so this isnt really an answer

Comment: Alright, Thanks for clearing.
I will see if i can do somthing

Comment: @YaserAbdulrahman Thanks for the help, but i found the problem. Content-Type: application/json is used to post data. But I'm trying to get data so i need to use Accept:application/json.

Comment: @FlubberBeer You could answer your question then and earn some reputation